# Run FME Workbench with Python

Tags: python, fme-form, python-2.6

I would like start/run FME workbench from one external python script. Is there some simple syntax/command to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You could do a call to [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html). Something like:

```
os.system workspace.fmw --arg_one --arg_two ...
```

Look in the Log window when you run your workspace and at the very top it will give you the command to run, it's usually in blue and says "Windows command-line to run this workspace:".

Comment: Yes. It is very easy.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to run a second workspace using python command in "Shutdown Python Script" in the first workspace using the following command. I just copied what Chad has written but its giving me an error. Is there anything I need to do different?  Thanks, Sam  import os

os.system fme.exe C:\temp\test2.fmw
          --SourceDataset_ARCGIS_LAYER C:\ScratchParcel\DevEnv.gdb\AddressPoint
          --DestDataset_SHAPE C:\temp

Comment: Sam can you post a new question on GISse please, thanks